# Unable to locate element link

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate 'Search' link, however I'm getting the following error:
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
    {"method":"link text","selector":"Search"}

I inspected the object using Firebug:

```
<li onclick="submitSelectedTab('tabSelected', 'TabGroup1', '12');" title="Search">
    <a href="#">
        <span>Search</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The code I tried to use was

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Search")).click();
```

I've also tried:
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Search")).click();

I've also tried running the IDE which came back with:
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForPopUp |
    _blank | 30000]]

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[title=\"Search\"] > a > span")).click();
```

The above code didn't work either.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but to get to that page a new tab was loaded.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference that new tab was loaded. :D Why are you opening a new tab, is that necessary?

Comment: It didn't come through the first time I posted it. Is the above html enough?

Comment: Yes, it's how my UAT environment loads after I sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to the new tab

```
// get original tab handle
String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// open the new tab here

// switch to the new tab
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handle.equals(currentHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Search")).click();

// close the new tab and switch back to the old tab
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. You are awesome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Search')]")).click();
```